# full lenght Hexa value is not converting in full length string in C?

Tags: c

I m working on an IR project when we pressed the button the value are store in struct

```
typedef struct
{
    decode_protocol_t decode_protocol;
    unsigned long hexavalue;
    unsigned int address;
    unsigned int magnitude;
    int bits;
    int rawlen;
    int rawbuf[500];
    char *protocolString;
} receive_cmd_t; 
receive_cmd_t results;
```

To print the hex value.

```
printf("0x%lX", results->value);
Output:  0xA1DE11EE
```

Now I just want to convert this A1DE11EE value into the string format.

For that, I used snprintf function. Here is my code.

```
unsigned long value = A1DE11EE;
char hex[sizeof(value)*10];
snprintf(hex, sizeof(hex), "%lX",value);
printf("HEX value:%s\n", hex);
```

I was expecting `HEX value: A1DE11EE`. What I got `HEX value: A1D`

I tried to increase the hex buffer but still, it's giving the same output.

I did not understand why it's happening?

And also how I convert back into hexadecimal `0xA1DE11EE.`

Sorry for giving less explanation of the issue.

Comment: `unsigned long value = A1DE11EE;` this doesn't compile. please show a [mcve]

Comment: Don't you get some syntax error while compiling?`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. After listening to the complaints by the compiler (e.g. here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php ) I get as output: `HEX value:A1DE11EE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solving the compiler error (assignment to `value`) and warning (`snprintf` misspelled as `snprinf`) is enough to make the program work

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned long value = 0xA1DE11EE;  // note the 0x
  char hex[sizeof(value)*10];
  snprintf(hex, sizeof(hex), "%lX",value);  // snprintf was misspelled as snprinf
  printf("HEX value:%s\n", hex);
  return 0;
}
```

This will print

```
HEX value:A1DE11EE
```